# ERR: Pod is in pending stage FailedScheduling : nodes didn't match node selector

Tags: kubernetes

Guys I'm trying to fix issue with Jenkins pod
my pod is in `Pending` status
kubectl describe output **Warning  FailedScheduling  26m (x44 over 92m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.**

Can you please advice where issue may come from.
I'm stuck with this issue and didnt find helpful similar issue
.
.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    section: tools
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: jenkins
    section: tools
  clusterIP: None

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-0
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    section: tools
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: jnlp-port
      port: 50000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 50000
  selector:
    app: jenkins
    section: tools
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: jenkins-0

    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
      name: jenkins
      namespace: jenkins
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        section: tools
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      serviceName: jenkins
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: jenkins
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: jenkins
            section: tools
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: jenkins-account
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: drokh-jenkins
          containers:
          - name: jenkins
            image: docker.xyz.com/jenkins/jenkins:v0.1
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            env:
              - name: JAVA_OPTS
    #            value: "-Xms2g -Xmx2g -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"
                value: "-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
              - name: JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT
                value: "50000"
    #            - name: JENKINS_OPTS
    #              value: "--prefix=/jenkins"
    #        livenessProbe:
    #          httpGet:
    #            path: "/login/"
    #            port: 8080
    #          initialDelaySeconds: 90
    #          periodSeconds: 10
    #          timeoutSeconds: 5
    #          failureThreshold: 5
    #        readinessProbe:
    #          httpGet:
    #            path: "/login/"
    #            port: 8080
    #          initialDelaySeconds: 60
    #          periodSeconds: 10
    #          timeoutSeconds: 5
    #          failureThreshold: 3
            ports:
              - name: http-port
                containerPort: 8080
              - name: jnlp-port
                containerPort: 50000
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: "2Gi"
                cpu: "250m"
              limits:
                memory: "16Gi"
                cpu: "8"
            volumeMounts:
              - name: jenkins-home
                mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: jenkins-home
          spec:
            accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
            storageClassName: "jenkins-storage"
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 80Gi
    
    ---
```

kubectl get nodes

```
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
k8sc2m1   Ready    control-plane,master   727d   v1.22.2
k8sc2m2   Ready    control-plane,master   727d   v1.22.2
k8sc2m3   Ready    control-plane,master   727d   v1.22.2
```

Comment: The pods wont get scheduled to nodes as there are no worker nodes in the k8s cluster.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal yes you are right previous employee not correclt set up kubernetes.
Also not only jenkins any sample deployment same issue

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal
 what is your advice to solve issue

Comment: @ShukurilloBaikhanov This issue can be resolved by adding new worker nodes to the existing cluster. Once the new worker nodes with sufficient resources are available this issue will be resolved. follow this [blog](https://monowar-mukul.medium.com/kubernetes-create-a-new-token-and-join-command-to-rejoin-add-worker-node-74bbe8774808) for more information on how to add new nodes to the existing cluster

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni but this is very old kuber. adding new worker with old version is not solution for now as we have limited time. How about change master to worker role is it solution? as all 3 nodes role is master.

Comment: @ShukurilloBaikhanov are there any existing applications running on this cluster...? as you are saying this cluster is created by previous employee if there aren't any production level applications running on this cluster it is suggested to recreate this cluster from the scratch

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni yes there is running app on this cluster. creating from scarcth not for now as we have limited time

Comment: @ShukurilloBaikhanov then you can remove the master node taint as mentioned in this [blog](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-schedule-pods-on-kubernetes-control-plane-node/) it will be helpful for scheduling your pods on master nodes as well.

Comment: The current k8s cluster nodes can be rebalanced based on your requirements, either having two master nodes and one worker node or Have one master node and two worker nodes.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni As you suggest we decided to start kube from scratch.
The problem is migrating jenkins to new kuber because jenkins deployed as stateful set. How to migrate with all data to new kuber. plz give advice,article, post thx